# Update last inserted record in Django

Tags: django

In Django, I want to retrieve the last inserted record from the database and update its values.

I use this model:

```
def User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I run the following code to retrieve the last inserted record and update the name:

```
User.objects.last().update(name=‘NEW NAME’)
```

However, the error is that update is not a known method.

Does .last() indeed return the entire record, or only the primary key?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `.last()` returns a model object, so that means you can not call `.update(..)` on it.

Comment: Hi Willem. Can you recommend an alternative to update that update model?

Answer (score 6):

> Does `.last()` indeed return the entire record, or only the primary key?

[**`.last()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#last) returns the *last* `User` object, or `None`, if there is no such record.

Now a single model object has indeed *no* `.update(..)` method. Only a `QuerySet` has an [**`update(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) method. You thus can for example retrieve it, alter the field, and then save the object:

```
last_user = User.objects.last()
if last_user is not None:
    last_user.name = 'NEW NAME'
    last_user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

you must at first get the user model then use last like this 
`user = User.objects.all().last()`
 and now you can update with this code 
`user.name = 'Daniel'
user.save()`

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you model/database is this

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Then you go to the terminal and start the shell to do some testing. For that you do

```
python manage.py shell
```

In the shell, first you need to import your database/model

```
from nameofyourapp.models import User
```

To get the last element you could write

```
lastUser = User.objects.all().last()
```

Now change the last User

```
lastUser["name"] = "Josh"
```

Save the changes

```
lastUser.save()
```

Exit from the terminal